# Using regular expressions to match the first pattern occurrence in each line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using regular expressions with Python, attempting to parse through the data below.

**The Data thing1 =**

```
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=IDXG&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">IDXG</a>, 
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=INVN&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">INVN</a>, 
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=SWC&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">SWC</a>, 
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=NE&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">NE</a>,
```

The regular expression

```
pattern = "[A-Z][A-Z]{1,5}(?![A-Z])"
match = re.findall(pattern,thing1)
print(match)
```

The result I get is the two occurrences in every line.

```
['IDXG', 'IDXG', 'INVN', 'INVN', 'SWC', 'SWC', 'NE', 'NE']
```

The result I want is only the first occurrence that matches the pattern in each line.

```
['IDXG', 'INVN', 'SWC', 'NE']
```

I know that if I remove the global tag, it stops after [one match.](https://regex101.com/r/02Fhkr/5)

And if I do each line separately, it'll give me the [first match.](https://regex101.com/r/02Fhkr/6)

Is there an elegant way to get the first occurrence of each line in Python?

Comment: Try `pattern = ">([A-Z]{2,5})<"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added a < to your second link:

```
[A-Z]{1,5}(?![A-Z<])
```

[Your updated link](https://regex101.com/r/02Fhkr/7)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
pattern = "([A-Z][A-Z]{1,5}(?!\&)).*\n"
match = re.findall(pattern,thing1)
```